# Specific cordova hooks in config.xml per platform

Tags: node.js, cordova, hook, config, platform

I was trying to use  to run specific nodejs scripts per pratform.
In the docs it says it is possible set a hook per platform:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_hooks_index.md.html

If i put the hooks in config.xml outsite of the platforms tags, the scripts will be called:

```
<hook type="before_platform_add" src="HookInstallPluginsWP8.js" />
<hook type="before_platform_add" src="HookInstallPluginsIOS.js" />
```

But if I put it inside a  tag it does not run:

```
<platform name="wp8">
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>

    <hook type="before_platform_add" src="HookInstallPluginsWP8.js" />
</platform>

<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>

    <hook type="before_platform_add" src="HookInstallPluginsIOS.js" />
</platform>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be supported until Cordova 5.x.  Are you sure you are running the latest Cordova?

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: yes, I'm using cordova 5.3.3 and also tested with the last version 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reason why this was happening.
Today I tried to add `<icons>` and `<splash>` images to my project and I faced the same situation. The icons and splash were not added if inside a platform tag.

In my case this was happening because inside a `<platform>` tag, it only could exist one type of tag.

For example:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
    <hook type="before_platform_add" src="HookInstallPluginsAndroid.js" />
    <icon  src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png density="ldpi" />
</platform>
```

In this case the hook and the icon will be ignored.
I have to add different `<platform>` nodes:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true"/>
</platform>
<platform name="android">
     <icon  src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png density="ldpi" />
</platform>
<platform name="android">
    <hook type="before_platform_add" src="HookInstallPluginsAndroid.js" />
</platform>
```

Is this a documented case? I did not found anything on cordova docs... maybe it's just a bogus situation?